# CSS Grid Layout Gap Box Sizing

Tags: css, grid

I have a CSS grid that occupies 100% width and 100% height of a window (the body element has `display: grid;`). The grid has row and column templates and elements which occupy 100% of their allocated space. However, when I add a `grid-gap` to the grid, it makes the grid too large for the window, forcing scrollbars to appear. How can I stop the `grid-gap` from adding to the dimensions of the grid - similar to how `box-sizing: border-box;` stops padding from adding to the dimensions of an element? Instead, I want the gaps to shrink the cells of the grid.

Thanks.
[image: like this]

Comment: Please add your code :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It works same as if you used `box-sizing: border-box` and padding as you can see in this demo. Height is set to 100vh and you can see that if you remove or add `grid-gap` there is no scrollbar, you just need to remove margin from body.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  background: #FF7D7D;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr; /* Use Fractions, don't use % or vw */ 
}
.grid > div {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
div.a, div.d {
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
  <div class="c">C</div>
  <div class="d">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked when I used `fr` units as in your code instead of percentages.

Comment: I was using vw units and ran into the same issue as the OP, but only on Windows Chrome (worked fine on Mac Chrome).  Using fr units works well for me on both platforms.

Answer (score 18):

When you use "fr" it works.

#### Example:

- HTML:

```
<section>
    <article class="a">A</article>
    <article class="b">B</article>
    <article class="c">C</article>
    <article class="d">D</article>
</section>
```

- SCSS:

```scss
section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    grid-gap: 20px;

    border: 10px solid blue;
    
    article {
        background-color: tomato;
        
        &.d {
            grid-column: 2; 
            grid-row-start: 1; 
            grid-row-end: 4;

            background-color: olive;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use view-port units:

- `vw` (1% of window's width)
- `vh` (1% of window's height)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}

.first {  height: 40vh;  }
.hori {  height: 10vh;  }
.second {  height: 50vh;  }


div > div {
  float: left;
}

.left {  width: 40vw;  }
.vert {  width: 10vw  }
.right {  width: 50vw;  }

.first .left,
.second .right {
  background: #ccc;
}

.first .right,
.second .left {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="grid-break vert"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>

<div class="grid-break hori"></div>

<div class="second">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="grid-break vert"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```